# Stored procedure plan optimisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 which queries a single very large & very busy table based on a few parameter values passed in. I have no control over the schema.

Most of the time the stored procedure performs very well but occasionally it seems to compile a REALLY bad execution plan (my guess is a table scan - which would be nuts with this table).

Whats the best way to optimise the stored procedure to avoid this? I'm currently trying `OPTIMIZE FOR` & using some sensible parameter values

However, I'm thinking I may be better off with `USE PLAN` & just force an execution plan I know works well (there are no `JOIN`s, just 3 indexes on the table, table size is pretty consistent (BIG!) so I think the plan shouldn't really need to change).

Anyone had experience with this kinda thing? what works best?

Comment: I usually check into parameter sniffing first thing. I have spent hours refactoring queries just to find that using a local variable instead of the parameter variable could have fixed it to begin with. I don't know if it will help you so this is not an answer, but here is a decent link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

Comment: Have you tried viewing the execution plan in SSMS?  It may give you a visual on which table is causing the performance hit.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your statistics are up to date? This could be an issue if there is a lot of UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE activity

Answer (score 1):

Grant Fritchey is a friend of mine at our local PASS chapter.

Any who, are you sure you do not have **parameter sniffing** going on?

It usually happens with skewed data.

If so, there are seven different ways to combat it.  Check out Grant's slides.

http://www.scarydba.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/LuckyConnections.pdf

But the key is to find / look at both the good and bad plans in graphical format.

Why is one better than the next.  Once you know what is happening, pick a way to fix it.

Good luck

J

Comment: Cool - thanks for the pdf, some interesting bits to look into.

Answer (score 0):

I think I cracked it - problem appeared to be parameters that resulted in no records from the underlying table.

I added a date predicate - even though the query doesn't really need one as it uses the integer ascending key to return the X most recent records.

This massively reduced the number of records searched when there are no matching records for a parameter value.

Hope this makes sense!

Thanks for the comments - its great to understand these things in more detail.